# C++ unordered_map string vs int key performance

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, int, unordered-map

Is there a significant difference in performance (if I'm doing random lookups), between using string and int keys? In my particular case, string keys are more convenient, but with a bit of difficulty, I could get a setup with int keys as well. I'm just wondering if it is worth the extra effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is pretty clear that hashing and comparing strings is generally more expensive than hashing and comparing `int`s.

Whether this is of any practical significance to your particular program, we can't tell. You'll need to profile your program and find out for yourself.

My advice is to to code for clarity and ease of maintenance, then profile and only optimize the bottlenecks.

Comment: Also, hashing will be more expensive (and likely more frequent) than comparing. However, if you would be doing your own hashing anyway, the comparing would be the main difference as both methods would need hashing.

Comment: That very much depends on the nature of the strings, as well as the stdlib implemenetation. If both use the same hash function for int and string, and the strings are on average about the size of an int, then things will likely be indistinguishable. As always: the best is to test it yourself, for your own data universe.